# Download the android by the Cygwin Terminal

Tags: android, source, download

I have a problem for download android by Cygwin Terminal in windows. I use this guide for download it:

```
 - 1) Download cygwin from http://cygwin.com/install.html.
 - 2) Install cygwin with defaults.In cygwin Select defualt page search

for curl and python and check them to be installed.

 - 3) Then start cygwin.exe

go to your preferred directory (mine is D:/Android/sources/4.0/try2 )
cd d:
cd Android/sources/4.0/try2

 - 4) Run the below instructions one by one
 - i) mkdir bin
 - ii) PATH=/cygdrive/d/Android/sources/4.0/try2/bin:$PATH
 - iii) curl https://dl-ssl.google.com/dl/googlesource/git-repo/repo >
   /cygdrive/e/android-s/bin/repo
 - iv) mkdir source
 - v) cd source
 - vi) repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest
   -b android-4.0.1_r1

give credentials

 - vii) repo sync
```

So, it work fine until 4-ii step but when I try to use of the 4-iii step it gives me this error:

```
-bash: curl: command not found
```

What is the problem? How to solve it?

Comment: Please post the result of `echo $PATH`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install curl package for cygwin by running the installation again and select the desired package(s).